# Replace checkbox with images angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have to style/replace all checkboxes and radio buttons with images.
I can do this easily by simply adding a span tag after every input(checkbox / radio) like.

```
<label for="rememberme">
  <input type="checkbox" class="unique" id="rememberme"/>
  <span class="icon-checkbox"></span>
</label>
```

How can i do this in angular js. 
I cannot modify all htmls with adding a span element, as if something went wrong it will take time to revert.
But i have a unique class or i can add an attribute to write a directive.

I tried using an attribute but i am unable to inspect span element generated, it is working good if i use it as an element.

If i use as an attribute it is giving an output as

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" custom-input="">
   <input type="text" class="form-control">
   <span class="icon-checkbox">Checkbox icon</span>
</input>
```

is this Valid ?

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/XbsYiy72StsG2ljNUc0E?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it working from your suggestions with out any change to HTML for easy fallback

```
.directive('input',function(){
    return{
        require: '?ngModel',
        restrict:'EAC',
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
          var html = angular.element("<span class='icon-checkbox'>Checkbox icon</span");

          if( (angular.lowercase(element[0].tagName)==="input") && (angular.lowercase(attr.type)=== "checkbox"))
              element.after(html)
        }
    }
})
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C4Bt1UbfBZ58b5opBp2L?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about a custom directive just to replace the checkboxes with images. You could do this with CSS like this:

```html
<!--HTML-->
<input type="text" class="form-control checkboxwithicon">
```

```css
/*CSS*/
.checkboxwithicon{
  position:relative;
}
.checkboxwithicon::after{
  content:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icojam/blueberry-basic/32/check-icon.png');
  position:absolute;
  top:-10px;
  left:15px;
}
```

And position the image properly so that the checkbox is hidden.

Comment: Have you tried this approach. I believe we dont have before or after pseudo elements on input tag

Comment: Certainly works on checkboxes. See [this] (http://plnkr.co/edit/cYWcRGKdAMWAyABF7JPf?p=preview).

Comment: Apparently so. I would wrap the checkbox with a <span> and add the pseudo-class to the span element. You could build the directive to do it for you. Not sure if that is what you are interested in. But here you go for a solution that works on FF: http://plnkr.co/edit/26Exgf8Nx2KYueBXUYVR?p=preview just in case.

Comment: Yes this works. But need to change lot of htmls, and if required to revert could be time consuming.   I am looking for something which i can write a directive for <input> tag directly and inject a span. If required i can remove directive definition from one place. I am trying Telvin approach

Comment: Sure, you could use a custom directive like this http://plnkr.co/edit/LCfrEjYTXCDxSypsIUwZ?p=preview from your original Plunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a directive that does generate the span icon-checkbox after the element (it's supposed to be a checkbox) for you and make it act like an attribute, then you can tag it in every input checkbox that you want. Even something wrong happens and you are not happy with the change, you don't have to waste your time and effort to revert the things back, just modify on the directive only.